# jQuery Siblings selector not work correctly

Tags: jquery, search, filter, siblings

I wanna to live search in page and filter match case. Because of that I use `:contains` to search text in page. At first I want to find `.col-3` that match with search text and after that I want to `hide` other siblings element. Now I understand `siblings()` not work correctly. It's a sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(':text').on('change paste keyup',function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     $('.col-3').css({'background':'#fff','color':'#000'});  

     if(val != ''){
         var el = $('.col-3:contains('+val+')').css('color','blue');
         el.siblings('.col-3').css('background','red');
     } 

  })

 })
```

What should I do?

**This is Complete Code**

https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/MGmZKq?editors=1010

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. Codepens/Fiddles etc should be supplementary, not key to understanding the question.

Comment: I added codepen sample, pay attention to bottom of question [https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/MGmZKq?editors=1010](https://codepen.io/essvision/pen/MGmZKq?editors=1010)

Comment: Pay attention to the above comment - links to code pen must be accompanied by the relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selector selected multiple items at the same time, hence type "h" can result 3 matches result, their sibling items will overlap with each other, which cause your problem. You can use `:not(:contains)` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(':text').on('change paste keyup',function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      $('.col-3').css({'background':'#fff','color':'#000'});  
    
      if(val != ''){ 
          var el = $('.col-3:contains('+val+')').css('color','blue'); 
          $('.col-3:not(:contains('+ val +'))').css('background','red');
      } 
    
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>ehsan</h3>
      <p>expert</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>mahdi</h3>
      <p>employee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>farhad</h3>
      <p>manager</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>sara</h3>
      <p>employee</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```